# for /f in batch scripting

Tags: scripting, batch-file

echo %DATE% will display something like this:

sri 09.01.2013

Here is the script:

```
for /f "tokens=2-4 usebackq delims=. " %%i in ('%DATE%') do set fileName=testing_%%i_%%j_%%k
echo %fileName%
```

When I run this script, I get the output like this:
The system cannot find the file ?§♦ź♫↕.
testing_09_01_2013
As you can see, the concatenated string is fine, but why am I getting message that system cannot find the file with some garbage at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it..
Instead of ('%DATE%') should be (`date /t`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value in parentheses must be *a string enclosed in quotes* OR *a command enclosed in apostrophes*. Although you solved your problem using `('date /t')` COMMAND, it is more efficient and simpler to use `("%DATE%")` STRING instead:

```
for /f "tokens=2-4 usebackq delims=. " %%i in ("%DATE%") do set fileName=testing_%%i_%%j_%%k
echo %fileName%
```